# Can I specify other source directories in Xcode preferences such that gdb will use them for find sources?

Tags: xcode, debugging, gdb

I know about specifying source locations using gdb. But I am wondering if there's someplace in my Xcode project or other settings where I can specify source directories such that gdb would use whatever I specify to look for sources. If I could put them in Xcode settings I think it would help me save them in a central place.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to - if the sources are part of your project and are used to build your executable, and so long as you are generating debug symbols, then gdb should be able to find the source files. The only time I can think of that this might fail is if you build on one machine and then try to debug on another, where the paths to the source files are different.

Comment: Paul - That's my situation: the paths are different.

Comment: Can't you just rebuild on the target machine ? Or does that take too long ?

Comment: And how about the situation when you have the source for an external library but don't have an Xcode project for it?

Comment: @ctpenrose: that shouldn't matter, so long as you build with -g. Why the down-vote ?

Comment: @PaulR it looks like your answer isn't a general solution, just a specific fix for an unusual situation.  Lots of times you get a .a file + src + headers, but the .a is built with makefiles from the command line somewhere else.  The information included with -g isn't enough, there needs to be a way to point Xcode to the root of the source tree for the .a.

Comment: @James: note that my answer was for Xcode 3.x, back in 2010 - the situation may have changed with Xcode 4.x (I don't know - I don't use Xcode 4.x much). If you feel the answer is no longer helpful I'm happy to delete it.